# TableView object At Index Selection

Tags: iphone

In my Application , iam binding data through JSON Webservices, iam loading data in a Tableview.Based on the selected value in the Table view , i have to bind data in another table view from the following Webservices.

```
    http://hrmsiphone.atrity.info:7006/HRMSService.svc/DisplayEmpSalaryDetails/
    Unit=A-upper,Category=Staff.
```

Heres the Tableview Coding,

```
     Unit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.Details1            
     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     NSLog (@"THE SELECTED UNIT IS: %@", Unit);
```

But when i select the Value from the Tableview , it passes values as {\n  UNIT = "A-Upper"; /n}, But i need to get only "A-Upper".I tried many ways, but i doesn't get the values right.Any ideas regarding this may be helpful.

Comment: Show value of `self.Details1` in log.

Answer (score 2):

`self.Details1` is array of dictionaries. So first , you have get the value from the dictionary, something like as follows.

```
NSString *val = [[self.Details1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Unit"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is a group of dictonary so first you have to parse it like this

```
NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [self.Details1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Unit = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"UNIT"];
```